# Adding page number

Tags: page-numbering

I searched some of the questions related with this subject on TeX.SX., but i couldn't manage to understand which one fits for me. I want page number to be displayed on all pages of the document; table of contents page, list of figures page, chapters' first pages ...
I have added some part of the code I use :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\geometry{ a4paper, total={210mm,297mm}, left=27.5mm, right=27.5mm, top=30mm, bottom=20mm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\newlength{\spacelength}
\settowidth{\spacelength}{\normalfont\ }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand*\protect\addvspace[1]{}}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1.5em}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
Some text..
\newpage
Some Text.
\newpage
\begin{center}
\tableofcontents{}
\end{center}
\chapter{IntroductioN}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Some Text..
\newpage 
\section{section}
Some text..
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to redefine "empty" for the fancy package, because the standard classes automatically switch to empty on pages where chapters start. The fancyhdr doc explains how this is done in one entire section.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf `s/empty/plain/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On chapter pages, the `plain` page style is used by default. You have to either redefine the `plain` page style using `fancyhdr` or (the easier one) make `plain` equal to `fancy like

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother
```

Your code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\geometry{ a4paper, total={210mm,297mm}, left=27.5mm, right=27.5mm, top=30mm, bottom=20mm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\newlength{\spacelength}
\settowidth{\spacelength}{\normalfont\ }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand*\protect\addvspace[1]{}}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1.5em}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
Some text..
\newpage
Some Text.
\newpage
\begin{center}
\tableofcontents{}
\end{center}
\chapter{IntroductioN}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Some Text..
\newpage
\section{section}
Some text..
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty method is to remove `\thispagestyle{plain}` from `\tableofcontents` or the `\chapter` start - up pages using a `\xpatchcmd` from `xpatch` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,fleqn]{report}

\usepackage{xpatch}%
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\geometry{ a4paper, total={210mm,297mm}, left=27.5mm, right=27.5mm, top=30mm, bottom=20mm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\newlength{\spacelength}
\settowidth{\spacelength}{\normalfont\ }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand*\protect\addvspace[1]{}}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1.5em}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}


\xpatchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
Some text..
\newpage
Some Text.
\newpage
\begin{center}
\tableofcontents{}
\end{center}
\chapter{IntroductioN}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Some Text..
\newpage 
\section{section}
Some text..
\end{document}
```

[image]